# InputField autocomplete

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make an InputField like the one shown below in Unity. I don't see any way I could do this in Unity. I also want to use google places autocomplete API.I am using Unity v5.6.1f1 .Is this possible?.

[image: Like This]

Comment: You should take a look at the [OnValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html) event of the InputField class

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Jan Yes, I did.

Comment: @azemda care to share your solution? Thanks!

Comment: Actually it's been a while since I've done this and don't have the code right now, but I'll do this again and share as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little script I made to give you an idea :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Autocomplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField inputField;
    public RectTransform resultsParent;
    public RectTransform prefab;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener( OnInputValueChanged );
    }

    private void OnInputValueChanged( string newText )
    {
        ClearResults();
        FillResults( GetResults( newText ) );
    }

    private void ClearResults()
    {
        // Reverse loop since you destroy children
        for( int childIndex = resultsParent.childCount - 1 ; childIndex >= 0 ; --childIndex )
        {
            Transform child = resultsParent.GetChild( childIndex );
            child.SetParent( null );
            Destroy( child.gameObject );
        }
    }

    private void FillResults(List<string> results)
    {
        for (int resultIndex = 0 ; resultIndex < results.Count ; resultIndex++)
        {
            RectTransform child = Instantiate( prefab ) as RectTransform;
            child.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = results[resultIndex];
            child.SetParent( resultsParent );
        }
    }


    private List<string> GetResults( string input )
    {
        List<string> mockData = new List<string>() { "Paris", "Madrid", "London", "Rome", "Brussels", "Athens", "Dublin", "Lisbon", "Amsterdam", "Luxembourg" };

        return mockData.FindAll( (str) => str.IndexOf( input ) >= 0 );
    }

}
```

Attach this script to the inputfield, drag & drop in the inspector the input field, a RectTransform with a `VerticalLayoutGroup` component (to layout correctly the results), and a Text prefab (or any UI component you want with a child containing a `Text` component).

Currently, you should replace the content of the `GetResults` so as to retrieve the results from your library. Since I don't know this library, you will have to do it on your own ;)

Comment: I was in the middle of sorting this out, I'll post my version of solution soon enough, thanks for the reply.